# Uniqueness of Radon measures

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose that $\mu,\nu$ are Radon measures on $\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\int fd\mu=\int f d\nu$ for every $f$ continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support. I was told that the equation $\int fd\mu=\int f d\nu$ implies that $\mu=\nu$ by the Riesz Representation Theorem (for Radon measures). Why is this the case? I can't find any connection to this theorem to conclude that $\mu=\nu$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is immediate from the uniquness part of Riesz Therem for locally compact spaces. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem

Comment: I do not understand, how this just implies that $\mu=\nu$ .The way I understand this theorem is that once a linear functional is given, it is possible to make it equal to an integral of a function with respect to a measure, and this such measure is unique. In our case, what is our linear functional here? Is it $\int f d\mu$ or $\int f d\nu$?

Comment: Since the two integrals are given to be equal you define the linear functional as $F(f)=\int f d\mu =\int f d\nu$. @UnknownW

Comment: Okay, then either way, we get by this theorem that for some unique Radon measure $\eta$, we get $F(f)=\int f d\eta$ for all $f$. Then, how does it imply or tell us that $\mu=\nu$? I am sorry for asking silly questions, I am just trying to understand

Comment: @UnknownW That is exactly what uniqueness means in the statement of the theorem. You cannot have to different measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ such that $F(f)=\int f d\mu =\int f d\nu$ for all $f$, so it better be true that $\mu =\nu$.

Comment: Thanks for your patience